# Angular js controller not working after modularizing app

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and followed the tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp) from w3schools to create my first simple Angularjs app and it worked fine. After going through the official angularjs tutorial I decided to modularize my app but now its not working. Currently I m getting the error

> "The controller with the name 'redController' is not registered."

I want to display a message in component 'red' using its controller. I tried altering many parts of the code only to get new errors  and it seems I have messed up modularizing  :|

I'm using v1.6.9

Here is my directory structure

```
app/
    scripts/
        angular.min.js
        angular-route.js
    blue/
        blue.template.html
    red/
        red.template.html
        red.module.js
        red.component.js
    app.config.js
    app.module.js
    index.html
```

and source files :

app.config.js

```
angular
.module("myApp", [ 'red','ngRoute' ])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/red", {
    templateUrl : "red/red.template.html",
    controller: "redController"
})
.when("/blue", {
    templateUrl : "blue/blue.template.html"
});
});
```

app.module.js

```
 angular.module('myApp', [
'red',
'ngRoute'
]);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>



<script src="app.module.js"></script>
<script src="app.config.js"></script>


<script src="red/red.module.js"></script>
<script src="red/red.component.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <a href="#!red">Red</a>
  <a href="#!blue">Blue</a>
  <div ng-view></div>
  <p>Click on the links to navigate "</p>
</body>

</html>
```

red.template.html

```
<h1>red</h1>
<p>{{msg}}</p>hell
```

red.module.js

```
angular.module('red', [ 'ngRoute' ]);
```

red.component.js

```
angular.module('red').component('red',{

        templateUrl: 'red/red.template.html',
        controller: function redController() {
            this.msg = "this is red";
            console.log("Hi");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are delcaring the module again and again in each .js files, declare only in one .js file and use it in rest of the fields.

change your **`red.module.js`** as,

```
angular.module('red', []);
```

your app.config.js should be as,

```
angular
.module("myApp")
.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/red", {
    templateUrl : "red/red.template.html",
    controller: "redController"
})
.when("/blue", {
    templateUrl : "blue/blue.template.html"
});
});
```

and change the order as follows,

```
<script src="red/red.module.js"></script>
<script src="app.module.js"></script>
<script src="app.config.js"></script>
<script src="red/red.component.js"></script>
```

Change red.component.js as follows

```
angular.module('red')
.component('red',{
templateUrl: 
'red/red.template.html',
})
.controller("redController",function($scope)
{
$scope.msg ="This is red";
});
```

Comment: I made the corrections and it still gives the same error !!

Comment: in the file red.component.js

Comment: Since you are using this it should be changed as controller as syntax

Comment: This is harder than i thought.. No progress

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @Sajeetharan you're defining the `myApp` module twice. Inside your `app.config.js` and also in `app.module.js`. If you use `angular.module` with 2 parameters `angular.module('app', [])` you're setting the module, if you use `angular.module('app')` it'll work as a getter. So, in your `app.config.js` you should use the getter to configure your app.

Once you did that, you can configure your route to something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/red', { template: '<red></red>'});
})
```

I would use this approach since you defined the component in another module.

If you still want to use the approach you've implemented to set both the `templateUrl` and `controller` in the `$routeProvider`, you'll have to change your `red` component declaration to something like this:

```
angular.module('red')
.component('red', { templateUrl: 'red/red.template.html'})
.controller('redController', function(){
    this.msg = 'This is red.';
});
```

I'vent tested this second approach as for me the first makes more sense.